# Is it possible to add a username a password to a hostname in /etc/hosts?

Tags: macos, ubuntu

Is it possible to add a username a password to a hostname in `/etc/hosts`?

Like: a.b.c.d     `username:password@hostname`

Comment: A host file exists for creating manual host mappings. These apply to all services, not only ssh so placing a username or password in there doesn't make any sense. You should better explain what you want to do instead of trying to do something with the wrong "ingredients".

Comment: Have you read any documentation on the `hosts` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passwords for associations between IP and Host Name are not needed (at least 99% of the time).

So, the HOSTS file use as defined cannot use passwords.

Answer (score 0):

No. The hosts file cannot parse additional data - only the IP address and Hostname.